# How can I make the power amplifier stage for this audio amplifier?

Tags: power, amplifier, audio

How can I implement a Power Amplifier stage for powering an 8 ohm load? I tried making an AB amplifier, but either it doesn't work or I'm just not able to make one. The output of the third op-amp is a 20V sine wave. This, however, can be changed. I just can't seem to be able to make a power amplifier stage for such a low output impedance...

[image]

Comment: You need to change all the stages to include DC midrail biasing for the non-inverting inputs.

Comment: Plus, all 3 op amps need a 10k resistor from the + input to ground.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated topic, and entire books have been written on it. It would be wise to start with those.

A resource I recommend is Bob Cordell's [Designing Audio Power Amplifiers](http://www.cordellaudio.com/book/). Cordell does an excellent job explaining how to design high-quality Class-AB audio amplifiers.

Comment: I don't need anything fancy. Actually, even that 30W is a major overkill. I just want a power amplifier that works, no matter the efficiency.

Comment: If 30 watts is overkill, just how much power DO you need? And what sort of components are you willing to work with? Op amps only? Power transistors? Do you have heat sinks available?

Comment: Cordell's presentation is a tutorial format, starting with a simple amplifier and progressively improving the circuit until it has amazing performance (of course, at the cost of amazing engineering effort). You can choose to get off the improvement train at whatever point you choose.

Comment: You could also have a look through the ESP articles. Some good advice on there:  http://sound.westhost.com/articles.htm